# Is it possible to export each separate soil layer from a stratigraphical 3d-model, using Midvatten and Qgis2threejs plugins?

Tags: qgis-plugins, 3d, geology, qgis-export

I would like to create a 3d-stratigraphical modell in QGIS and thereafter separate each soil layer to stand alone shp-files. I believe that my best shot to do this is with the plugins Midvatten and Qgis2threejs.

Does any one know if this is possible?